# What is Aruna Prashna?

Tags: yajur-veda, krishna-yajurveda

The Aruna Prashna is a part of the Taittiriya Sakha of the Krishna Yajur Veda.

Aruna is the name of the charioteer of Surya.

What does this section talk about?

Comment: First prapathaka of Taittiriya Aranyaka constitutes 32 Anuvakas; It's called Aruna Prashna used primarily for praising Surya and related rituals.